# recover a removed fortran file if have executable

Tags: ubuntu

I have accidentally removed a .f file I was working on in my local Ubuntu machine. Would there be a way to recover it? Usually the answer would be no but what if I have its executable? I have used the "rm" command. Unfortunately is the only new file from the latest backup.

Comment: first thing, stop any writing now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install foremost`

Open the file `/etc/foremost.conf` and you will see a long list of commented out lines. Leave them commented out. What you need is a line like this (first column is file type):

```
f     n       40000   <start of your code>     <end of your code>
```

The 2nd column refers to case-sensitivity, the third column refers to the upper limit for size, the 4th column is how the file starts (remember to use escaped characters) and the last column is how the file usually ends. Edit the value accordingly.

Use the following command (edit the disk accordingly. could check with `df` command):

`foremost -v -T -c /etc/foremost.conf -i /dev/sda -o output`

What will happen next is that foremost will create a folder called output and dump all the recovered data (in this case) into the folder. From there you could use diff or meld to compare the recovered 'files' and see which is the most up-to-date.

Comment: hi R.L. thanks for the hand. I do as you suggest adding line:
    "f    n    40000    <MODULE modulename>    <end module modulename>" 
but unfortunately all I get out of it are huge numbers of small (~kb) nonsense files. probably it has to do with my start of code and end of code strings?

Comment: if you remember how big the file is, you can change 40000 to slightly above the size of the file in bytes.

If you can remember the first line of the file and the last line that also helps. Don't forget to escape the string literals for this part.